# How to match and merge lookup results in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm a total newbie with Excel and I'm stuck at doing this. I'm guessing there must be some work around "lookup" functions but I don't know which one and how to start.

Let's say I have a first sheet with 2 columns:

| ItemA | ItemB |
| --- | --- |
| plane | apple |
| bus | banana |
| bus | strawberry |
| car | pear |

As you can see, the first column does not contain unique values ("bus" appears twice)

I have a second sheet with two columns:

| ItemA | ItemB |
| --- | --- |
| plane |  |
| bus |  |
| car |  |
| car |  |
| plane(carriage return)car |  |

Here again, the first column can have duplicates (here "car") but also a single cell can contain several values separated by the CR (carriage return) character.

What I'd like is to find a function that will take all values of (ItemB) from the first sheet and copy them into the ItemB column of the second one.

So the "bus" item will have "banana(carriage return)strawberry", the two "car" will have "pear" filled up and "plane(carriage return)car" will have "apple(carriage return)pear" value in column ItemB.

Second sheet will be:

| ItemA | ItemB |
| --- | --- |
| plane | apple |
| bus | banana(carriage return)strawberry |
| car | pear |
| car | pear |
| plane(carriage return)car | apple(carriage return)pear |

Is it possible to do such thing?

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome! `microsoft-excel-2010`? Oh, no - for this version the solution can only be found with a macro or with PowerQuery installation. Since you say that you are a "total newbie with Excel", it is unlikely that you will cope with this task on your own. So the answer to your question is "No, it can't be done"

Comment: Hi, I actually have Excel 16, I fixed my issue, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data tab contains all the tools needed to accomplish this task.
First, convert the original data into tables. Name the first table "SourceTable" and the second "TargetList".
Now create a new request and replace its code with the following

```
let
    ListByRef = (celltext, table) =>
        let
            MakeTable = Table.FromList(Lines.FromText(celltext), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            MergeValues = Table.NestedJoin(MakeTable,{"Column1"},table,{"ItemA"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.Inner),
            Extract = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeValues, "NewColumn", {"ItemB"}, {"ItemB"}),
            ClearTable = Table.SelectColumns(Extract,{"ItemB"}),
            SingleCell = Lines.ToText(Table.Column(ClearTable , "ItemB"))
        in
            SingleCell, 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
    Target = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TargetList"]}[Content],
    SingleColumn = Table.SelectColumns(Target,{"ItemA"}),
    Result = Table.AddColumn(SingleColumn, "ItemB", each ListByRef ([ItemA],Source))
in
    #"Result"
```

[image: Result]

*(For more information about using PowerQuery for various transformations of tabular data, see [**the training videos on YouTube**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+query+excel))*

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)